# TeeChart WPF Histogram color of bins

Tags: wpf, histogram, teechart

I am using TeeChart and the Histogram Series to display data.
I would like to color the bins individually depending on the values but all I found was the option to color each one differently. I want the bins displaying the same value to have the same color. Is that possible with TeeChart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You can achieve that either providing the color value when populating the series using the appropriate Add method override or using the BeforeDrawPoint event as shown here:

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  InitializeChart();
}

private void InitializeChart()
{
  tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false;

  Histogram histogram1 = new Histogram(tChart1.Chart);

  histogram1.LinePen.Visible = false;
  histogram1.LinesPen.Visible = false;

  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
  {
    histogram1.Add(i);
  }

  histogram1.BeforeDrawPoint += histogram1_BeforeDrawPoint;
}

void histogram1_BeforeDrawPoint(Series series, BeforeDrawPointEventArgs e)
{
  series.Colors[e.ValueIndex] = (series.YValues[e.ValueIndex] > 10) ? Color.Red : Color.Blue;
}
```

Comment: The Add method with color parameter was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!